# Is The First Order in any way related to Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, revenge-of-the-sith

After watching The Force Awakens I couldn't help but make a connection between Order 66 from Episode III and The First Order regime in TFA.

Could this be Palpatine's "Order 1", something along the lines of "in the event of my death carry out these plans"?

Comment: Not an answer, but I got the feeling that the first order was to exterminate the Jedi.

Comment: Which could make sense, as they try to kill a certain Jedi.

Comment: Too lazy to make this an answer, but there's a big chance First Order was at least [partially a riff on Third Reich](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115423/976).

Comment: @DVK-in-exile _Partially_?

Comment: @DavisJensen - T.R. wasn't led by whiney teenage emos

Answer (score 5):

No, probably not.

The word "order" in English has many different meanings. [The English Oxford Dictionary](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com) lists [nine](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/order) of them.

"Order" in "Order 66" uses the Oxford Dictionary's second meaning: "command, instruction, request." Before *The Clone Wars* animated series introduced the bio-chip story arc, Order 66 was a part of the Senate-approved document "[Contingency Orders for the Grand Army of the Republic: Order Initiation, Orders 1 Through 150](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Contingency_Orders_for_the_Grand_Army_of_the_Republic:_Order_Initiation,_Orders_1_Through_150)." Some of video games and books featuring clone troopers provided insight into the document and quoted some other orders that the soldiers had to know. Unfortunately, this is Legends now.

"Order" in "First Order" uses the Oxford Dictionary's fourth meaning: "A society of monks, nuns, or friars living under the same religious, moral, and social regulations and discipline." Consider the sub-meaning 4.1 in the light of the fact, that Snoke was overseer of both Knights of Ren and First Order.

It doesn't have to mean anything, but the Polish translation translated "First Order" into "Najwyższy Porządek.” In this context, the word chosen for "First" directly translates to "Highest". However, I'm not sure if official translators were provided with some undisclosed information in order (*sic!*) to provide a more accurate translation, or that was just the translator's gut feeling.

Comment: I think it could be interpreted partially symbolic, I guess. The First Order rose out of the ashes of he fallen empire, which itself rose from the ashes of the first galactic war (both separatist and republic). But in every other way, you are right.

Comment: Is this list canon? I mean, it's very strange that the senate publicly voted an order that could led to the extinction of the Jedis and that the Jedis are unaware of...

Comment: @Tloz no, it is not considered Canon since Disney took over. But look at Order 65, which dealt with event of "Supreme Commander (Chancellor) unfit to issue orders". This and Order 66 can be seen as belonging to "never going to happen, but we are prepared; hooray bureaucracy!" category. Additionally, convoluted language and length (other order refers to "page 1173") of documents produced by Senate made it impossible for anyone to really see through what is happening. Personally, I find this idea much more appealing than bio-chip that short-circuited brain and turned clones into zombies.

Comment: That's curious. If something like that was voted by thousands (billions?) of people in the senate, the Jedis would have seen it coming (have "a bad feeling about this" or whatever ^^)
I always thought that the order 66 as a kind of backdoor installed in clones' brain by Palpatine or Sifo-Dyas/Dooku

Comment: @Tloz Senate did not vote for bill that made it legal to kill Jedi; it voted for bill that made it possible to participate in war that has already started. It was probably one of hundreds of bills that had to be urgently passed and most of senators were not really paying attention to details. Member of parliament that doesn't know what exactly they vote for is a thing that happens all too often here on Earth, so I don't see why it should be rare in SW universe. As for Jedi, they had a galactic-scale war to attend to - they could have let that one slip through.

Comment: Order 65, Order 66, Order 01: In the event of repeated military setbacks, there shalt be a splinter faction with shinier stormtroopers, led by two emotionally immature youngish adults, who will report to a creepy guy with a funny name who shall be projected as being amazingly large.